# Структура мини-проекта React

Tags: reactjs, архитектура

Доброго времени суток. 
Хочу сделать простую форму для ввода данных в React;

Есть таблица, в столбце возраста по клику появляется окно, где предлагается указать возраст. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запутался на правильной реализации структуры. 
1) Как я понимаю, то любое действие пользователя должно создаваться в actionCreator'e. Т.е. код popUpWindow должен находиться в action и соответственно экспортироваться в контейнир, получается, что action будет классом, так? 
2) Если и всплывающее окно и таблицу сделать в одном файле, то как тогда грамотно организовать передачу данных между ними?

Мой container

```
class Popup extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='popup'>
        <div className='popup_inner'>
          <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>
          <form>
            <input type="text" value="Введите возраст"></input>
          </form>
        <button onClick={(event) => { this.props.closePopup(); }}>ok</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TableOfNames extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.props = { term: "" };
    this.popUpWindow = this.popUpWindow.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      showPopup: false
    };
  }

  popUpWindow() {
    alert('Здесь должно выпадать меню');
    this.props.addValue();
  }

  togglePopup() {
  this.setState({
    showPopup: !this.state.showPopup
    });
  }

  alertMethod() {
    alert('Запустился метод другого класса!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="table table-bordered">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Имя</td>
              <td>Фамилия</td>
              <td>Возраст</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Петя</td>
              <td>Бесов</td>
              <td>...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Вася</td>
              <td>Иванов</td>
              <td>...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Энрике</td>
              <td>Гуакамоле</td>
              <td onClick={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}>...</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        {this.state.showPopup ?
          <Popup
            closePopup={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}
          />
          : null
        }

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас всё в кучу: React, redux, actionCreator-ы... Не усложняйте задачу на старте!

> Хочу сделать простую форму для ввода данных в React;

Так и используйте React!

> Есть таблица, в столбце возраста по клику появляется окно, где
>   предлагается указать возраст.
>
> 1) Как я понимаю, то любое действие пользователя должно создаваться в
>   actionCreator'e.

Только если у вас уже подключен редакс, и то не каждый чих нужно делать через экшены. Экшены логично использовать когда вам, например, нужно передать данные из одного компонента в другой - то, что встроенными средствами реакта вы делали бы дольше с большим количеством возможных ошибок по пути.

> Т.е. код popUpWindow должен находиться в action

Нет, в данном случае это избыточно

> и соответственно экспортироваться в контейнир, получается, что action
>   будет классом, так?

Нет, action - это простая функция, возвращающая тип события (например, строку или Symbol) и, если нужно, данные.

> 2) Если и всплывающее окно и таблицу сделать в одном файле, то как
>   тогда грамотно организовать передачу данных между ними?

Средствами реакта это всё можно сделать. Данные идут от родителя к потомкам через пропсы, а наверх передаются родителям через обработчики (заданные опять-таки в пропсах). Другое дело, что в крупных проектах так уже слишком неудобно делать - источником всех-всех данных будет самый верхний компонент, и чтобы организовать взаимодействие разноуровневых компонентов и иметь корректное состояние данных придётся приложить очень много усилий (плюс бороться с большим количеством ошибок). Именно поэтому используют redux или flux - они помогают решать эту проблему и создают десяток новых :) Но вы же фронтенд-разработчик, так что не должны бояться трудностей)

Здесь немного сокращённый вариант, ниже (на JSFiddle) подробнее.

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
     Hello {this.props.name}
      
      <TableOfNames />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

class Popup extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
     inputValue: '',
    };
    this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleOnChange(event) {
    this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value })
  }
 
  handleSubmit() {
   this.props.togglePopup();
   this.props.onSubmit(this.state.inputValue);
  }
  
  render() {
   const { placeholder } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className='popup'>
        <div className='popup_inner'>
          <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>
          <form>
            <input type="text"
                value={this.state.inputValue || placeholder}
                   onChange={this.handleOnChange}
         ></input>
          </form>
         <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>ok</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TableOfNames extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.togglePopup = this.togglePopup.bind(this);
    this.handlePopupSubmit = this.handlePopupSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      showPopup: false,
      popupText: '',
    };
  }

  togglePopup() {
    this.setState({
      showPopup: !this.state.showPopup
    });
  }

  handlePopupSubmit(text) {
    console.log('handlePopupSubmit', text);
    this.setState({
     popupText: text,
    })
  }

  render() {
   const text = this.state.popupText || '...';
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Имя</th>
              <th>Фамилия</th>
              <th>Возраст</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Энрике</td>
              <td>Гуакамоле</td>
              <td onClick={this.togglePopup}>{text}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        { this.state.showPopup &&
          <Popup
            togglePopup={this.togglePopup}
            onSubmit={this.handlePopupSubmit}
            placeholder="Введите возраст"
          />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
.popup {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.popup {
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Рабочий пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/globadaniil/9tjs4oxz/44/)