# Архитектура мини-игры React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доброго времени суток. Есть небольшой проект на React/Redux, очень интересует правильная архитектура.

В redux store хранится двумерный массив, который предварительно генерируется по клику. В контейнере массив перебирается и отображается на странице как таблица. Для некоторых значений в этой таблице по клику должно вызываться popup окно рядом с ячейкой, на которую кликнули. Так как я слабо освоил Redux начинаются сложности.

1) Должен ли я создать отделенный компонент для popup или добавить его в существующий container?

2) Как и куда нужно передавать координаты всплывающего окна, чтобы оно всплывало непосредственно рядом с кликнутой ячейкой.

3) Где должен храниться код для генерации массива в reduce или в actionCreator, а так же код который меняет state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понятно зачем вам тут контейнер и что он из себя представляет. Если это просто компонент внутри **App**, то я бы изобразил его внутри жёлтого прямоугольника (на схеме). Что касается архитектуры,

> 1) Должен ли я создать отделенный компонент для popup или добавить его
>   в существующий container?

Это не важно, вы можете вынести код/верстку вынести в отдельную функцию `renderPopup()` или в отдельный компонент `<Popup />`, сути это не меняет - как вам удобнее с точки зрения расположения модулей. К редаксу это отношения не имеет.

> 2) Как и куда нужно передавать координаты всплывающего окна, чтобы оно
>   всплывало непосредственно рядом с кликнутой ячейкой.

Этого и не потребуется (заморачиваться с координатами). Если вы так отрисуете компоненты, что popup-ы будут внутри ячеек, то добавив ячейке `position: relative`, а popup-у `position: absolute`, всё будет показываться где надо.

> 3) Где должен храниться код для генерации массива в reduce или в
>   actionCreator, а так же код который меняет state?

Это зависит от того, на каком этапе вам нужно изменять данные. Если у вас есть запрос к серверу (например), и перед отправкой этого запроса нужно изменить какие-то данные - можно сделать это в *экшене*. Обычно же в экшене вообще ничего не вычисляется, я про это [уже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795331/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-react/796945#796945) писал.

Если вам нужно поменять данные в *redux-сторе* (например, после получения данных от сервера), то можно это сделать в редьюсере (особенно, если нужен доступ к объекту стора).

Если вам нужно менять *state*, то делается это только из компонента через метод *setState* компонента. Другое дело, нужен ли вам стейт, если вы используете *redux*, иногда только его и достаточно (но не всегда).

Comment: Да спасибо, проект действительно слишком прост, чтобы использовать redux, просто хотелось немного прощупать его.